# SQL Partial primary key, composite key

Tags: sql

In the author/title entity the two "primary" keys should act together as a primary key , how can i do that in sql. Do i need to create a new key that hold those values? I know you're not allowed two have two primary keys in a entity but i didnt know how to write that they were compiste key/ partial primary keys. Im using sql server 2008

Here's the link to the er diagram  ( http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/3048/68810818.png )

[image]

Comment: you can select two attributes as primary key or primary key(author,title) should help

Comment: @spandy If i do primary key (author,title) then i would need a new key that hold those attributes. How would i select those attributes to act as a primary key without creating a new key. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-primary-key.html - for "doing it from SQL". In SSMS, select both columns from the Table editor and Choose "Primary Key".

Comment: @Sebastian try doing what pst said, that is how you add pk for multiple attributes

Comment: @pst It was that easy huh =) Thanks

Comment: @Sebastian That being said, with the exception of Linking Tables, I usually use *surrogate PKs* and *unique indices to enforce rules*. I really *would* like to use more compound PKs, but they generally end up making much more work - and since the same requirements *can* be captured in an additional/covering Key (unique constraint) .. of course, SQL databases are flexible, and this flexibility should be exploited insofar as it does not make a system [excessively] complicated or brittle.

Comment: The `Author_name` definitely should **not** be part of the pk. Only use running numbers/guids for Pk's

Comment: @Magnus - I strongly disagree with the idea that only "running numbers / guids" should be used for PK's.  That's the Microsoft way, yes, but there are two schools of thought on this.  The *purpose* of a primary key is to express something - it expresses that all data in the table is "about" that particular key.  There may be surrogate keys - a SSN, a running number, a GUID, etc. - which are unique and may be used to identify a particular record, but those are not generally "what the data is about."  Using running numbers as primary keys is a short-cut to actually thinking about the data.

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet Primary keys should be stable and single purpose. Once assigned a value that should never change and the pk attribute should have no purpose other than entity identification. Having PKs such as `UserName`, `SSN` or `LicensePlateNo`... are bad choices.

Comment: @Magnus That's certainly one philosophy, but there is no compelling argument for it.  What you advocate is based upon the idea that the storage structure is paramount.  What I advocate (and academic database texts advocate) is that the data is paramount.  As I've said, though: there are two schools of thought, here, and their differences certainly won't be resolved by bald assertions, particularly not in a comment thread.

Comment: @pst As to it being the Microsoft Way - yes, certainly it is.  In taking the SQL Server MCP exam, years ago, I took it twice in the same day: the first time through I modeled my tables with proper keys (e.g., `UserName` as PK) and failed the exam.  An hour later I retook the exam & modeled the tables with `identity` fields as keys and passed.  In MSAccess, if you do not select column(s) as PK in table creation, you're prompted to "add a primary key" which means you end up with a Counter field.  It's Microsoft's philosophy, espoused by @Magnus in comments.  They may not be originator, but...

Comment: @Magnus Although I structure my primary keys around the data elements which are logically primary, I use surrogate keys for the purposes of relating one table to another.  That's what surrogate keys are *for*, in my opinion: to make data access function more smoothly, and so that related data tables do not require updates in the event that the primary key changes.  In the event that a `username` changes, the related data remains the same, because it is associated via the surrogate key.  This keeps the structural model clean - `username` is what the table is "about" - and keeps relations clean.

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet since the primary key is the (default) clustred index of the table that is the one key to use as fk for releated tables. Maybe you should have taken a hint when you failed the exam for using "proper" primary keys. If you could point out any source online supporting your claim that would be great.

Comment: @Magnus No need to get nasty, please.  As I've said: using the counter field as primary key is one philosophy.  You'll find that if you're using GUIDs as primary keys and clustering on those, you'll run into rebalancing your indexes overly much.  Also, clustering is a separate issue - I cluster based upon what will optimize data access (how the data is sorted has some effects upon locking and querying), rather than taking the "default" clustered index.  If you're writing your own DDL statements, you choose how to cluster, and there is no "default" clustering (except in the background, hidden).

Comment: @Magnus As to pointing out an online source, I'd think you could search one up on your own, rather than asking me to do so.  If you're truly interested, pick up a database theory text - one which goes into the data science behind constructing database engines, rather than simply using them.  If you're interested in understanding how MSSQL structures its indexes and physical data structures, well, I can't think of a source off-hand, other than MSDN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without going into correctness of you model, the composite (aka. compound) primary key can be created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "Author/Title" (
    author_name VARCHAR(50),
    isbn VARCHAR(13) REFERENCES "Item Details",
    PRIMARY KEY (author_name, isbn)
)
```

This will allow the same `author_name` to have different `isbn` and still be considered unique (and vice-versa).

The similar effect can be accomplished from the SQL Server Management Studio, by marking both fields as part of the PK.

Comment: In keeping with the discussion above, it might be better to use surrogate keys, rather than the keys themselves, for this table.  In other words: use some ID field to relate the two - that way if the `author_name` changes you don't have to cascade the change down to this table, because the ID field wouldn't change.

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet Surrogates have their place, but are not free, and should not be used blindly. I'm fully aware of the ON UPDATE CASCADE issue, but there are [other considerations](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info) as well.

Comment: "Surrogates ... are not free."  Well, no, they're not *quite* free, except in certain circumstances.  In the case that you have no clustered index, SQL Server builds a RowID field in the background,  a clustered index on that field, and maps all other indexes into that clustered index.  So, although you don't see it, it costs just as much to build a table **without** a surrogate in that instance.  If you're overly concerned, or are dealing with huge datasets, I can see where you'd want to consider carefully.  In the above case, however, there would be performance gains plus no cascading need.

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet If there is a natural key in the table, surrogate cannot replace it. I'm not sure what the OP is trying to model here, but if (s)he's trying to say that no same combination or these two fields can exist more than once, then we **must** have this natural key, whether the surrogate is also present or not. As for your clustering argument, clustering serves for range scans, which are fundamentally incompatible with surrogates. The natural key above (which is also a clustering key, since NONCLUSTERED was not used) nicely clusters the rows belonging to the same author together.

Comment: "...range scans are fundamentally incompatible with surrogates."  I don't believe this to be the case.  For example, if deletes are performed in this linking table for authors, and the surrogate keys are clustered `(author_id, isbn_id)` then the delete (or query) will be optimal, taking fewer resources.  Whether there's an argument for adding an *additional* `identity` field to this table is another story, of course.

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet Sorry, I don't understand your argument. If you try to delete all rows that belong to the same author, then clustering on the natural key `{author_id, isbn}` is exactly what you need. OTOH, clustering on a surrogate physically puts the whole table in whatever is the ordering of that surrogate, which is typically insert order (for auto-increment) or even "random" (for GUIDs) and typically not very useful for the client application. I don't understand what you mean by: _"the surrogate keys are clustered (author_id, isbn_id)"_ - care to clarify?

Comment: If you are using surrogates to form the relationship between the Author table to the Author_ISBN table, you'd have two fields in the Author_ISBN table: Author_ID and ISBN_ID.  If, in the Author_ISBN table, you build an unique, clustered index on `(Author_ID, ISBN_ID)`, any removal of an Author from the Authors table would need to be carried through to the Author_ISBN table (naturally), but the data in Author_ISBN would be clustered, with all of each author's records in adjacent rows.

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet OK, we misunderstood each other. I though you were talking about adding a surrogate key in "Author/Title", you were actually talking about adding a surrogate in (presumably) "Author" table, which I agree would be appropriate. This surrogate would than migrate to "Author/Title" and become part of its natural key.